# How to calculate average of some timespans in C#

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, timespan

I already search this question but unfortunately couldn't find proper answer.

I want to calculate the average of time spent on doing something in 10 different day and I have 10 `datetimepicker` for start time and also 10 `datetimepicker` for end time for each day (in total 20 `datetimepicker`).

now I want to get the average of time spent for work in these 10 days.

this is what I've done for calculating `timespan` in each day and now I don't know how to calculate average if these `timespans`

of course I want to know is there any shorter way to get the job done?

```
DateTime Dt1 = dateTimePicker1.Value;
DateTime Dt2 = dateTimePicker2.Value;
.
.
.
DateTime Dt20 = dateTimePicker20.Value;

TimeSpan Day1 = DateTime.Parse(Dt11.TimeOfDay.ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(Dt1.TimeOfDay.ToString()));
TimeSpan Day2 = DateTime.Parse(Dt12.TimeOfDay.ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(Dt2.TimeOfDay.ToString()));
.
.
.

TimeSpan Day10 = DateTime.Parse(Dt20.TimeOfDay.ToString()).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(Dt10.TimeOfDay.ToString()));
```

I want to find average of Day1 to Day10

Comment: Well it would be a lot easier if you had an array or a List instead of 20 separate variables, to start with. (It's not clear why you're formatting `TimeSpan` values and then reparsing them, either.)

Comment: add them all up and divide by the number. And as skeet says - put them in an array

Comment: I'm curious.  Why did you decide to create a string just to parse it back again?  I'm really interested on your motivation on that, because I see that approach all the time and it's never required, nor desirable.

Comment: Also, are you guaranteed that all pairs of values are on the same date? Or could you have a pair that spans midnight, such as two hours between 11pm and 1am?

Comment: @MattJohnson Honestly this is my first time working with `datetimepicker` and I parse it back just because I saw someone did that in one of topics,

Comment: @MattJohnson yes all of these pair are only in 1 day from 00:00:00 to 24:00:00  not in midnight

Comment: @SaraniO - sure, but might your user pick them out of sequence?

Comment: @JonSkeet would you give me a hint to how do what you said ?

Comment: @MattJohnson yes it could happen that user entered wrong time :( and it's another question that how could I face these cases ?

Comment: If all DateTimes have the same Date, why strip it off? You are only interested in the differences anyway. So `var MyTimeSpan = myDateTime1 - myDateTime2;` seems to do the trick without `TimeOfDay` or `ToString()` (that last one is really amazingly useless but incredibly common for some reason).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Given an `IEnumerable<TimeSpan>` you can average them with this extension method:

```
public static TimeSpan Average(this IEnumerable<TimeSpan> spans) => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(spans.Select(s => s.TotalSeconds).Average());
```

So, convert your results to a `List`:

```
var durs = new List<TimeSpan>();
durs.Add(Dt11.TimeOfDay.Subtract(Dt1.TimeOfDay));
durs.Add(Dt12.TimeOfDay.Subtract(Dt2.TimeOfDay));
.
.
.

durs.Add(Dt20.TimeOfDay.Subtract(Dt10.TimeOfDay));
```

Now compute the average:

```
var avgDurs = durs.Average();
```

PS: Created an `Aggregate` version of @MattJohnson's answer:

```
public static TimeSpan Mean(this IEnumerable<TimeSpan> source) => TimeSpan.FromTicks(source.Aggregate((m: 0L, r: 0L, n: source.Count()), (tm, s) => {
        var r = tm.r + s.Ticks % tm.n;
        return (tm.m + s.Ticks / tm.n + r / tm.n, r % tm.n, tm.n);
    }).m);
```

Comment: It would be better to use ticks instead of seconds, to not lose any information in the finer precision.  Though probably doesn't matter in the OP's case, coming from a picker control, if one is going to keep an extension method around, one would want it to be usable in a variety of scenarios.

Comment: @MattJohnson Adding ticks can become a problem when overflowing. Seconds is a better option then.

Comment: thanks but I get this errore:
`'List<TimeSpan>' does not contain a definition for 'Average' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Average(IQueryable<int>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<int>`

Comment: add this `using System.Linq;`

Comment: @PatrickHofman - true, but there are [other averaging methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895559/average-function-without-overflow-exception) that can be used to overcome that.  Though I do agree with you in this particular case. :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman - see my answer below for how that can be overcome. :)

Comment: @MattJohnson FYI, `TimeSpan` is accurate to the millisecond which is why `FromSeconds` takes a `double`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman @MattJohnson doing the math implies that it will overflow if your total `TimeSpan`exceeds 29,227 years, which I imagine is fine in most circumstances. OTOH, while seconds lose precision, they are good for about 1,084 times as long a period.

Answer (score 5):

You can find average by instantiating a new TimeSpan based on number of ticks.

```
    var time_spans = new List<TimeSpan>() { new TimeSpan(24, 10, 0), new TimeSpan(12, 0, 45), new TimeSpan(23, 30, 0), new TimeSpan(11, 34, 0) };

    var average = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt64(time_spans.Average(t => t.Ticks)));

     Console.WriteLine(average);
```

result  `17:48:41.2500000`

Answer (score 4):

Just to follow up on NetMage's perfectly good answer, note that his `Average` extension method is using `.TotalSeconds`, which returns a `double` of whole and fractional seconds, with millisecond precision.  That is probably fine if you are taking values from time-pickers, but in the *general* case it will result in a small loss of precision.

Additionally, the `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` method can overflow when dealing with large values.  This can be reproduced even when not averaging:

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeSpan.MaxValue.TotalSeconds)  // will throw an OverflowException
```

Patrick Hofman made a good point in the comments that just switching from seconds to ticks could also result in overflow, and thus another solution is needed.

Adapting the technique given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2896452/634824), we can compute the average of a collection of `TimeSpan` values using an [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) approach, without loss of precision and without overflowing:

```
public static TimeSpan Mean(this ICollection<TimeSpan> source)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    long mean = 0L;
    long remainder = 0L;
    int n = source.Count;
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        long ticks = item.Ticks;
        mean += ticks / n;
        remainder += ticks % n;
        mean += remainder / n;
        remainder %= n;
    }

    return TimeSpan.FromTicks(mean);
}
```

Use it similarly to other extension methods, such as:

```
TimeSpan average = mylistoftimespans.Mean();
```

Comment: thanks
what should I do for negative ticks?
how could I check them and multiply them in -1 if they are negative?

Comment: There's no extra code needed to handle negative values.  Everything here is signed.

Comment: Seems like a good time for a complicated `Aggregate`. BTW, why us `ICollection` instead of `IEnumerable`?

Comment: To avoid possible two enumerations due to having to call `.Count()`

Comment: I created an `Aggregate` version over `IEnumerable` (not all `IEnumerable` implement `ICollection`) and interestingly `Mean` of (5,10,15) seconds returns a slightly bad result versus `Average`, though over a sample of 7 `TimeSpan`s, `Mean` is more accurate. Note that `TimeSpan` seconds is accurate to the millisecond.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me it was a `double`.  I updated my answer.  I tested the scenario you described and didn't get a bad result with my implementation, so I think maybe something in using `Aggregate`.  (Again, I like your answer too; it works in the majority of cases, especially the one the OP described.)

Comment: You were right, my implementation had a subtle error that made it off a little :)

Comment: @SaraniO - please accept NetMage's answer.  It is a better fit for your question.  I just wanted this one here because it is likely to come up in search results.  Thanks.

Comment: @MattJohnson that was nice, but hardly necessary - now we are tied :)

Comment: @MattJohnson I did it :)
and tanks a lot for your answer because it was your answer that get me the idea to how adapt 2 answer to get what I need from my code.
anyhow tanks a lot to both of you <3

Comment: @MattJohnson Your Overflow example would seem to indicate a bug in `TimeSpan`.

Comment: It's not so much `TimeSpan`, but just due to `double`.  It's already a well known example, and [in the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromseconds#Remarks).