# Average date time value with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 datetime values in `hh:mm:ss` format.
how can I calculate the average of these values in c# ?

```
DateTime casaDate = DateTime.Parse(casaAvgTAT, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
DateTime ACDate = DateTime.Parse(ACAvgTAT, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
DateTime TermDate = DateTime.Parse(termAvgTAT, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: u better search out of it and please edit your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227676/how-to-calculate-average-of-some-timespans-in-c-sharp/47227754

Comment: What would the average of three points in time be? You probably mean [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-5.0) (ie durations).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate average of some timespans in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227676/how-to-calculate-average-of-some-timespans-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not sure what sense it makes to average a set of datetime (because they are points in time), you can average their ticks and convert back to datetime

```
new DateTime(new[]{casaDate.Ticks, ACDate.Ticks, TermDate.Ticks}.Average());
```

Be aware that this might not result in what you expect: averaging 6am jan 1 1999, 12 noon jan 1 2000 and 6pm jan 1 2001 doesn't result in 12 noon jan 1 2000..

I'm also not really sure what you mean by "in hh:mm:ss format" - datetime don't have formats, string representations of datetimes have formats..